# How to read android app info without context from a module?

Tags: android, android-context

In my android app I need to login to a remote server and send information about the app (version name, version code).
I know that I can read this information with the following code:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
String versionname = pinfo.versionName;
```

I can read also this information from gradle: "BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME".
The problem is that the login process is in a network module and I don't want to pass context as parameters to every network call.
The BuildConfig generated is relative to the module version and not to the version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to have Context in data layer. But it's not okay to duplicate code. So there is mechanics in OkHttp called Interceptor. It will be applied to each network call if you add it to configuring OkHttp Client.

```
class ApplicationInfoHeadersInterceptor(context: Context) : Interceptor {

private val appVersion = DeviceUtil.getAppVersionName(context)
private val osVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
private val deviceId = DeviceUtil.getDeviceId(context)
private val applicationId = context.packageName

@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val builder = chain.request().newBuilder().apply {
        header("APP-VERSION", appVersion)
        header("OS-VERSION", osVersion)
        header("OS", "android")
        header("DEVICE-ID", deviceId)
    }

    return chain.proceed(builder.build())
}}
```